# Elastic search - yellow status after open Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I downloaded elasticsearch and open in console. ES worked good and had status green. Next I downloaded Kibana and open - now I have still yellow status, also if I stopped Kibana.

I have info:

> [o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [4e84hhA] Cluster health status changed
>   from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[.kibana][0]] ...]).

How can I fix it and where I can find more information for this error?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the `.kibana` index has one replica shard and you have a single ES node running.

Run this and you'll get a GREEN status again:

```
PUT /.kibana/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```